# Вішалка чи вішак?

Tags: вибір-слова, іменники

[OnlineCorrector](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BA/) пропонує

> Для урізноманітнення мовлення замініть іменник вішалка на кращий
>   варіант: вішак.
>
> **Типово** - "Веселка на **вішалці** — мода, одяг, гардероб, колір."
>
> **Вдаліше** - "Веселка на **вішаку** — мода, одяг, гардероб, колір."

В СУМ-20

> [Вішак](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=14920&page=488) а́, ч., розм. Те саме, що ві́шалка 1, 3.
>
> [Вішалка](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=14921&page=488) и, ж. 1. Поличка або стояк із кілочками чи гачками, а
>   також окремий гачок для вішання одягу, капелюхів і т. ін. 2. розм.
>   Гардероб, роздягальня. 3. Плічка для вішання одягу.

Дійсно варто замінювати слово "вішалка" на "вішак", адже в СУМ-20 "вішак" з позначкою розмовне?

Comment: На мою думку вішалка - більш розповсюджене, хоча б тому, що вішак чую взагалі перший раз. Можливо його використовують в окремих регіонах України?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По-перше, варто звернути на текст на сайті Онлайн Корректора:

> Для **урізноманітнення** мовлення замініть іменник вішалка на **кращий**
>   варіант: вішак.

Я виділив два слова. "Урізноманітнення" - погоджуюся, але от із "кращим варіантом" - ні. Шукаючи інформацію в Інтернеті я набагато частіше натикався на слово "вішалка", а не "вішак". Крім того ж інформація із СУМу, а також із сайту [Словник.ua](https://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0) (де біля слова "вішак" стоїть позначка "рідко"), вказує на те, що кращим варіантом буде саме "вішалка", а не вішак".

Також додам, що це слова-синоніми. Окрім зазначеного мною вище джерела на це вказують також і [Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%96%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0) (де також є слово [плічка](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0) і [тремпель](https://uk.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C), які також можна використати для "урізноманітнення" нашого мовлення), і [Словник синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0) (знову ж біля слова "вішак" стоїть позначка рідко).

Отож, не зрозуміло, чому на даному сайті пише, що "вішак" - це "кращий варіант" (бо швидше навпаки), можливо це помилка і добре, що вам вдалося це помітити. Однак, гадаю, що якби ви використали слово "вішак" замість "вішалка" чи навпаки, то все ж великої біди не трапилося, бо у нашій мові можна спокійно вживати як одне, так і друге слово.